# What rows are in view of a QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a custom QTableView with a custom QAbstractTableModel. I update every row where data has changed. The class that manages the data has a dirty flag which works well to help cut down the number of updates.

When I have a large number of rows, 1000 or more, the table gets a little less responsive. Instead of a for loop for each row to check it is dirty, I'd like to just loop over the 20 or so rows visible to the user, but I can't seem to determine how to get that information.

Is there a method or a convenient way to determine what rows are visible to a QAbstractTableModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will update only the rows visible to the user:

```
minRow = treeView.rowAt(0) # very top of scrollable area
if minRow >= 0: # ensure there is at least one row
    maxRow = treeView.rowAt(treeView.height()) # very bottom...

    # there may not be enough rows to fill scrollable area
    if maxRow < 0: maxRow = model.rowCount() - 1

    for row in range(minRow, maxRow + 1):
        model.dataChanged.emit(model.index(row, 0), model.index(row, model.columnCount()))
```